# Variant with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, std-variant

Sorry if this case is rather complicated, but I hope it helps people to better understanding modern c++ usage. So I want to make this code works. It should produce special lambdas for single integral type and for variant type for calculate sequence of terms on hard static cast to single type or on soft variant cast to common type, while this terms will be using. I add comments which describes what I really try to do in this code.

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <any>
#include <utility>

/* Visitor */ 
// Should get values from a variant
template <class... Ts>
struct Visitor;

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct Visitor<T, Ts...> : T, Visitor<Ts...> {
    Visitor(T t, Ts... rest) : T(t), Visitor<Ts...>(rest...) {}
    using T::operator();
    using Visitor<Ts...>::operator();
};

template <class T>
struct Visitor<T> : T {
    Visitor(T t) : T(t) {}
    using T::operator();
};

/* Calculator */
// Should get special lambda for same type integrals and for variant packed integrals
template<class T, class... Ts>
class Calculator {
public:

    // lambda for simple calculate same type integrals
    static auto sum = [](T a, T b) { return a + b; };

    // api for get current value of variant
    template<typename... Vs>
    static auto variant_value(std::variant<Vs...> v) {
        return std::visit(Visitor<Vs...>{}, v);
    }

    // lambda for unpack variant arguments calc common value and pack in variant again
    template<typename... Vs>
    static auto variant_sum = [](std::variant<Vs...> a, std::variant<Vs...> b) {
        auto value = variant_value<Vs...>(a) + variant_value<Vs...>(b);
        return std::variant<Vs...>(value);
    };
    
};

/* Term Producer */
namespace term::legion {

    using std::function, std::any;

    template<typename T>
    function<any(any)> legion(auto& algebra) noexcept { // std::function<T(T,T...)
        function<any(any)> redex = [](std::any a) {return a;};
        // I delete code here because its not important now
       return redex;
    }

    // production lamda for single type values 
    template<typename T>
    std::function<std::any(std::any)> sum(T arg) noexcept {
        return legion<T>(Calculator<T>::sum);
    };

    // production lambda for variant type values
    template<typename ...Vs>
    std::function<std::any(std::any)> sum() noexcept {
        std::cout << "variant sum selected" << std::endl;
        return legion<std::variant<Vs...>>(Calculator<Vs...>::template variant_sum<Vs...>);
    };

}

int main() {
     // term contains lambda for single type  
     auto sm = term::legion::sum<int>();
     // term contains lambda for variant type 
     auto v_sm = term::legion::sum<char, int16_t, double>();
}
```

Comment: Please indicate how this code fails to work currently, i.e. a compiler error message, or the wrong behavior.

Comment: Depends on compiler, I try to understand all problem scope here: https://godbolt.org/z/3coPrrn5c

Comment: If the behavior differs across compilers, that's useful information. Please add those details, and do that in the question, instead of comments.

Comment: C++17 or C++20?

Comment: I still use C++17

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to make your code works...

Anyway, some problems/suggestions

1. maybe your `Visitor` works but you can make better using the classic way: variadic inheritance

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Visitor : public Ts...
 { using Ts::operator()...; };
```

and avoiding specialization and recursion

2. When you call

```
auto sm = term::legion::sum<int>();
```

you have, inside `sum()` (given that `Vs...` is `int`),

```
Calculator<int>::template variant_sum<int>
```

that call, inside `variant_sum` (given that `Vs...` is `int`),

```
variant_value<int>(a) + variant_value<int>(b);
```

that instantiate, inside `variant_value<int>(a)` (given that `Vs...` is `int`), a

```
 Visitor<int>
```

The problem is that `Visitor` inherit from is template paramenters and a class **can't** inherit from `int`.

To make a visitor, you need functions that works with all types of the variant but you have to works a little; for example, you can write a sort of operator-wrapper as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct foo 
 { void operator() (T const &) { } };
```

and a visitor as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Visitor : public foo<Ts>...
 { using foo<Ts>::operator()...; };
```

This way `Visitor<int>` inherit from `foo<int>` (not from `int`) and `foo<int>` as a `operator()` accepting an `int`.

This works as visitor but you ask

```
variant_value<Vs...>(a) + variant_value<Vs...>(b);
```

for the contained value.

3. And here come the big problem: you can't have the value from `std::visit`.

Or better... from `std::variant<int>` (a variant with only a type), you can. You can modify `foo<T>` as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct foo 
 { T operator() (T const & val) { return val; } };
```

and (with a couple of little other corrections) this call

```
auto sm = term::legion::sum<int>();
```

compile.

But the following `sum()`

```
auto v_sm = term::legion::sum<char, int16_t, double>();
```

because the resulting visitor (`Visitor<char, std::int16_t, double>`) contains **three** different `operator()` functions, returning **three** different types (`char`, `std::int16_t` and `double`).

But `std::visit()` must return a single type. Not different types according the type active in the variant.

So I suppose your code has to be completely rethinked.

Other little problems

4. the following declaration is good in C++20

```
template<typename T>
function<any(any)> legion(auto& algebra) noexcept
```

but in C++17 you can't use `auto` as placeholder for the type of an argument (except for generic lambdas); the correct C++17 way pass through an additional template parameter, so

```
template <typename T, typename U>
function<std::any(std::any)> legion (U & algebra) noexcept
```

5. Add `constexpr` for `sum` and `variant_sum` inside `Calculator`

```
static constexpr auto sum = ...

static constexpr auto variant_sum = ...
```

6. If `Calculator` has only `public` members, you make it a `struct`.

Comment: Thank you I I figured out several aspects, it remains unclear for me whether I can pass a reference to a static template function or whether I should design everything in such a way as to call a static function that will produce a new lambda every time.